How do you get Visual Studio to put the output in the Project folder?
I have a VS 2022 project that has an EXE. When the EXE runs, it wants to open files in the ./data/ and ./saves/ folders.
The problem is that when VS builds the project, it puts the output in myProject\bin\Debug\net8.0; consequently, my EXE can't find ./data/ and ./saves/.
Setting the 'Base Output Path' doesn't help, because it will still append .\Debug\net8.0 to whatever I put in there.
Using a 'Post-build event' doesn't help, because even though my EXE gets copied to the right place, pressing Run from VS, runs the copy in the Debug\net8.0 directory.
The ugly workaround is to put copies of ./data/ and ./saves/ in each of .\Debug\net8.0 and .\Release\net8.0
Has anyone solved this conundrum?

You can walk the directory tree from the running app directory up until you find the directories you are looking for. Something like while (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(dataBasePath,"data"))) dataBasePath = Directory.GetParent(dataBasePath);

Use relative paths to the folders, and go further up the hierarchy. Instead of ./data, use ../../data, which looks for it two levels higher in the tree (which would be in myProject). Each .. means up one level in the folder tree.

I may have miscounted levels. You may need ../../../data. I think I forgot to account for the bin folder.

you could create hardlinks to the folders, e.g. with mklink /D data ..\..\..\data for each debug and release

@yacc that's a good suggestion. Slight correction though, that's a soft/symbolic link, not a hard link.

When making simple command line tools copying needed files into bin-folder is the easiest, but using command line parameters to specify path is a much better (flexible) option and recent VS has a nice support to debug app with custom arguments. For more complex app, like yours, which require a certain folder structure (likely organized by installer), you can still use parameters. Though more common is an assumption, that debug builds are used locally (only release builds are published) any therefore #if DEBUG/#endif can help to alter paths in your case.

Set working directory in project properties to '$(ProjectDir)' can correct the relative path localization.

I know 2 approaches:

Force specify the output path:
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>your\output\path\</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>


Copy resources to the output path:
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="data\**">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="saves\**">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>




Solution #1 works perfectly.
Thanks!
